# Pointless, nonfuctional options in Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I use Tor Browser often enough on my Windows 7 PC to have a semi-permanent entry for it in my Start Menu, and when I hover the mouse over that entry, a submenu appears with a list of options:  "Open new tab", "Open new window", and "New private window".  I never paid much attention to this before (except to think that "New private window" was somewhat redundant), but today I tried "Open new tab" with Tor running.  I expected a new, blank tab to open in the existing Tor Browser window, but the actual response surprised me:  "Tor Browser is already running, but is not responding.  The old Tor Browser process must be closed to open a new window."  (As I said, I was **not** trying to open a new window.)  Canceling out of that dialog brought me to the main Tor window, which continued to function perfectly normally (i.e. Tor Browser **hadn't** crashed, as the appearance of similar dialogs usually implies.)
I assume that the sort of communication between the OS and the program that would be necessary for this to work has been blocked as one of Tor's security measures, but if that's true, shouldn't the appearance of this menu have also been blocked?

Comment: This might be better placed as a ticket on https://trac.torproject.org/